# Posting on facebook user wall a custom field

Tags: facebook-graph-api, post

Using facebook graph API and user access token(and cURL), I am posting message, photos to the user wall. Can anybody guide me, I want to post a photo, its description and along with this RATING(custom parameter/field). What I mean is, is there a way to add a custom field and publish/post on user's wall.